# Selecting one producer for multiple consumers

Tags: node.js, producer-consumer

In a Producer-Consumer case with multiple app instances, I know I am supposed to have some type of queue for the distribution of events to the consumers. But how do I deal with the producer?

I must query a database for objects with an expired deadline every minute. That will push work to a message queue, so distribution is not a problem. My concern is that if I have multiple instances of the app, I have to make sure that only one is producing work.

Am I supposed to solve this electing a cluster leader? Is there a common algorithm or library in NodeJS for this? My guess is that I will have to reach for some magic Redis command and make my instances aware of each other.

Answer (score 0):

There are always many different ways to achieve things, but my suggestion is to create an [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) outbox table in your database, where multiple producers throw the records to be published to the message queue.

Then, you can deploy a tool like [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) that does [transaction log tailing](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transaction-log-tailing.html) (reads the database transaction log) and pushes the message to whatever message queue technology you're using.

Please note that it's also a good practice to implement the idempotency check on your consumers to make sure they don't process the same message twice.

[Wix - How We Implemented Idempotency in a Billing System at Scale](https://www.wix.engineering/post/how-we-implemented-idempotency-in-a-billing-system-at-scale)